# How to set the time in datepicker when it is shown?

Tags: javascript, datepicker

In an application i use the Tempus Dominus v5.3 datepicker.

I have 2 fields: one for the start of the meeting and one for the start of a topic for a meeting. Default the start-topic date is empty and the start-meeting date is set.

I want when the datepicker is shown that the start-meeting date is used and not the current date. E.g. when the meetings is scheduled at 13:00 hours and the user presses at 09:00 the datepicker the default time in date-picker should be 13:00.

I notice that the defaultDate already sets the input field for the start-topic date.
useCurrent set to false allows me the use a different date but I do not know how?

Comment: Some reproducible code will help to know the problem statement better.